# error CS0103: The name "ressourcesText" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I set up a string named ressourcesText, which will be set as the text LblRessources

This is the code for this problem :

```
public void ressources()
{
    string ressourcesText = "Ressources:"
                        + "\n Wood :" + wood
                        + "\n Stone : " + stone
                        + "\n Wheat : " + wheat
                        + "\n Food : " + food;
}

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    LblRessources.Text = ressourcesText;
}
```

How can the text for LblRessources use the string ressourcesText? It usually worked this way.

Comment: you need to read up on what the term `SCOPE` means.. you cannot `access `resourcesText` when you are not declaring the variable as public outside of the methods  what is the compiler telling you when you compile the program..? you need to change the method of resources() from void to string and return resourcesText or assign it to a variable for assignment in the return..

Comment: No canonical I can find.  Read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx your variable is defined in a method, and so goes out of scope (and is collected) once the method completes execution.  You need to define the variable at a higher scope. In this case, you create a class-level variable that can be read/wrote to by all methods in the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `ressourcesText` is declared locally in the `ressources()` function.

Variables that are declared within `{ }` brackets are destroyed at the end of the bracket, and are called `local variables`.

To solve this you could make your variable global:

```
string ressourcesText;
public void ressources()
{
    ressourcesText = "Ressources:"
                        + "\n Wood :" + wood
                        + "\n Stone : " + stone
                        + "\n Wheat : " + wheat
                        + "\n Food : " + food;
}

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    LblRessources.Text = ressourcesText;
}
```

Now this isn't necessarily good practice, because at the time of declaring your variable, it will be null, and thus can not be used until you call `ressources()`.

Another alternative would be to return the variable through the `ressources()` function and calling it directly to retrieve the value, like follows:

```
public string ressources()
{
    string ressourcesText = "Ressources:"
                        + "\n Wood :" + wood
                        + "\n Stone : " + stone
                        + "\n Wheat : " + wheat
                        + "\n Food : " + food;
    return ressourcesText;
}

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    LblRessources.Text = ressources();
}
```

That's somewhat safer.

You should check out these links for more info:

[Local variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742(v=vs.71).aspx)

[C# Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)

[Scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx)